# Creating a List holding a differnet type in place with LINQ?

Tags: c#, mongodb, linq

Instead of writing a 4 line loop I would like to create a new `List` (Actually an `IEnumerable`) in place with LINQ. I know that I can supply a lambda expression to LINQ and it will map elements of a list using that expression, but will it change the type the `List` holds?

```
// My List of objects
List<MyDBDocType> myDBDocs = ...;
// How they are mapped
BsonDocument myDBDocAsBson = myDBDocs[0].ToBsonDocument(); 
// Function signature that takes a List that holds a separate type
MyDocCollection.InsertManyAsync([IEnumerable<BsonDocument> documents], ...);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`LINQ` has some methods, some will change the data type while some others will not.

For example, `Select` clause could change the data type:

```
//suppose your MyDBDocType has property called MyInt with data type: int
var result = myDBDocs.Select(x => x.MyInt); //this will result in IEnumerable<int>
```

But `Where` method retains the data type, it just filters the result according to the lambda expression:

```
var result = myDBDocs.Select(x => x.MyInt > 3); //this will result in IEnumerable<MyDBDocType>
```

Other `LINQ` methods like `First`, `Last`, `FirstOrDefault`, `Except`, `Intersect`, `Distinct`, `Skip`, `SkipWhile`, etc... also do not change the data type. But method like `Select` and `SelectMany` change the data type.

In your case, if you only want to filter certain results from the original query without having any change on the data type, consider using `Where`